# How exit from tomcat application manager?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have configured and run tomcat. Then I went to URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

entered "admin" as username and pass, that had been configured before. So after that I can see Tomcat manager, there are some deploy and undeploy controls but no "exit" or "unlogin" button. How I can log off from Tomcat manager?

Answer (score 15):

You have to close the browser window.

The Tomcat Manager application uses BASIC authentication and while there are a number of browser specific tricks applications can use to try and implement log off, closing the browser is the only sure way to do this.

Comment: this time I was 4 secs earlier than you

Comment: That is because I was typing more ;)

Comment: This doesn't work When I restart firefox, I am still logged in!

Comment: Then you haven't fully restarted Firefox. You need to close every Firefox Window. Check with the appropriate tools for your OS that no Firefox processes are running.

Comment: is there some session timeout ? how long need to wait after closing the browser ?

Answer (score 4):

close the browser simply to logout. when you again try to login then it will ask for username and password